# What happens when a bountied answer is undeleted?

Tags: support, reputation, bounties, deleted-answers

Say I have a question and I award a bounty to an answer, but the answer gets deleted. According to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/287795), my reputation as the one who awarded the bounty will not be refunded to me, and the reputation gained by the person who received the bounty will be nullified. So far so good.

But what happens if the answer is *undeleted*? Will the bounty amount be re-awarded to the person who posted the answer, or does deleting the answer permanently nullify that reputation?

Comment: Bonus question: what happens to the little blue `+X` label indicating that the answer received a bounty?

Comment: @MartinBüttner Pretty sure that stays, though I don't remember where I saw it once.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the answer is later undeleted, they will regain the amount of the bounty.

The bounty vote *itself* does not have anything done to it when the answer is deleted. It still exists on the post like any other vote (up, down, accept). The *reputation* is just retracted because the post is deleted. Undeleting the answer restores the post, and all the votes that were on it previously will still exist like normal, and when their reputation gets recalculated next to account for the undeleted post, they all get calculated back into the mix as they were.

Comment: To address Martin's ancillary question (see comment), if nothing is actually done to the bounty when the answer is (un)deleted, does that mean that the blue label denoting the bounty stays regardless? I assume so, just want to make sure.

Comment: @AlexA. The blue indicator never gets removed from the deleted answer in the first place. It will always display, even while deleted.

Comment: Okay, cool beans. Thanks!

Comment: Just to make sure, in case the answer has score of 3+ and is 90+ days old when deleting it, user keep the earned reputation. This applies for bounties as well, right?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes.